# Chrome Extension "contextMenus.create" title property validator?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to display a different menu text based on the selection:

***manifest.js***:

```
{
  "name": "Test app",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "icons": {"16": "icons/16.png", "48": "icons/48.png", "128": "icons/128.png"},
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/test.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***js/test.js***

```
function validateSelection(number) {
  if (parseInt(number) > 5) {
    return "Result: x > 5; (x = " + number +")";
  } else {
    return "Result: x <= 5; (x = " + number +")";
  }
}

var s_item = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title"   : validateSelection("%s") + " => Selection: %s",
                                         "contexts": ["selection"],
                                         "onclick" : genericOnClick,
                                         "enabled" : true
                                         });
```

However no matter what number I select I always get the output from the `else` clause in my `validateSelection()` function. What kind of object is passed to my function, is it `string`? How otherwise I can validate the `selection`?

1. [image: Selected number = 4]

   ---
2. [image: Selected number = 9]

Comment: Here is the feature request for more dynamic contextMenus: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a literal string `"%s"` to `validateSelection`, so `parseInt("%s")` is `NaN` which is why the `else` branch is always executed.  This is an immediately executing function which effectively returns `Result: x > 5; (x = %s)` and this string is used to create the menu item ONE TIME. Then every time you invoke the menu Chrome simply expands `%s` when the menu is displayed. It doesn't and can't pass this `%s` AGAIN into `validateSelection` because it wasn't a callback, it was an immeditely executed function as per javascript syntax.

The context menu title is not dynamic and there is no function callback parameter for the title.

To change it dynamically define a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that will be injected on `<all_urls>` with a `selectionchanged` event listener that will change the context menu title *before* it's shown.

content script:

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(e) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({selection: getSelection().toString()});
});
```

background script:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({id: "menuSel", title: "", contexts: ["selection"]});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    .......
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if ("selection" in msg) {
        chrome.contextMenus.update("menuSel", {title: validateSelection(msg.selection)});
    }
});
```

The pitfall is that if you select something in one tab without invoking the context menu, then switch to another tab and select something, then switch back and immediately rightclick the *already selected text*, the result will be wrong. This can be handled, though, in a [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) listener in the background script (may require `"permissions: ["tabs"]` in manifest.json):

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(info.tabId, {code: "getSelection().toString()"}, 
        function(results) {
            chrome.contextMenus.update("menuSel", {title: validateSelection(results[0])});
        }
    );
});
```

If you want to make it work on frames/iframes, use `allFrames: true` parameter in `executeScript` and determine which frame is active.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Please see added images. You can see `(x = 4)` and `(x = 9)` which are respectively defined in my function statements `"(x = " + number +")"`. If the literal string `"%s"` has been passed to my function, shouldn't I be seeing the `(x = %s)`?

Comment: Added the explanation into the answer.